# c++ convert texts like one two three as 123 and zero one two as 12 in a file and sort them like 12 123

Tags: c++, string, numbers

convert texts like one two three as 123 and zero one two as 12 in a file and sort them like 12 123 i am fetching the input from a file which contains this input .i got them printed but i cant sort them..i used atoi function to convert into number but then it prints 0. please help.

one two three

five seven

zero one two

three two one

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int findno(char * a);

ifstream fin;
int i=0,k=0,j=0,count=0,s=0;
char ar[100],ch,str[100],no[100][100];
int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
  fin.open(argv[1]);
  fin.getline(ar,100);

  while(i<strlen(ar))
  {
    if(ar[i]!=' ')
    {
      str[k++]=ar[i];
      i++;
      if(i==strlen(ar))
      {
        fin.getline(ar,100);
        no[s][j++]=findno(str);
        cout<<(int)no[s][j-1]<<"\n";
        i=0;
        k=0;
        j=0;
        s++;
      }
      continue;
    }
    if(ar[i]==' ')
    {
      no[s][j++]=findno(str);
      cout<<(int)no[s][j-1];
      i++;
      k=0;
    }
  }

  cout<<atoi(no[0])<<" ";

  fin.close();
  return 0;
}

int findno(char * a)
{
  if(a[0]=='z')
    return 0;
  if(a[0]=='o')
    return 1;
  if(a[0]=='t' && a[1]=='w')
    return 2;
  if(a[0]=='t' && a[1]=='h')
    return 3;
  if(a[0]=='f' && a[1]=='o')
    return 4;
  if(a[0]=='f' && a[1]=='i')
    return 5;
  if(a[0]=='s' && a[1]=='i')
    return 6;
  if(a[0]=='s' && a[1]=='e')
    return 7;
  if(a[0]=='e')
    return 8;
  if(a[0]=='n')
    return 9;
}
```

Comment: Too much C, didn't read.

Comment: First a simple [mapping](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) of the string to the digit, then ordinary arithmetic to convert the consecutive digits to a number, and the put in e.g. [a vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which you then [can sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Okay i will do it thanks! I dont know stl i will learn it though.But can u just tell why it prints 0 when i use this cout<<atoi(no[0])<<" "; in my code I hae used it earlier it works cant figure out why it doesnt here

Comment: Also learn how to use a debugger, it's going to be invaluable. Because with a debugger you can step through your code, line by line, while watching values of variables, and see what the code *really* does.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: From the stated fact that `12` sorts before `123`, we still can't tell whether lexicographical or numeric sorting is intended.

Comment: @Maneyy: Never, ever use `atoi`. Not only is there no reliable way to detect a failed parse, some failures cause undefined behavior.  Get used to using `strtol` instead.

Comment: Horrible title. Horrible text. No idea what all those one-letter variables mean. No idea what the result should be - `no[0]`, out of `no[100][100]`?

Answer (score 0):

> zero one two as 12

You can use flag signaling about presents non-zero character or not, as on example below. Set flag to false before reading next word, and set to true, if you found some non-zero character.

```
bool flag = false;
int tmp;
while(i<strlen(ar))
{
if(ar[i]!=' ')
{
  str[k++]=ar[i];
  i++;
  if(i==strlen(ar))
  {
    fin.getline(ar,100);
    tmp=findno(str);

    if (flag || (tmp > 0))
    {
      no[s][j++] = tmp;
      cout << tmp <<"\n";          
    }
    i=0;
    k=0;
    j=0;
    flag = false;
    s++; 
   }
   continue;
}
if(ar[i]==' ')
{
  tmp=findno(str);      
  if (tmp > 0)
    flag = true;
  if (flag)
  {
    no[s][j++] = tmp;
    cout << tmp;
  }
  i++;
  k=0;
}
}
```